# How to remove white space displayed in the place of of status bar in Xamarin android

Tags: xamarin.android, android-fullscreen, android-statusbar

I am trying to create a full screen mode(Like video player) application using Xamarin Android. Unfortunately, I am stuck on an issue, regarding white space displayed in the place of status bar.

I have attached here the screenshot about my issue.

[image]

Hear my code, on MainActivity:

```
Window.SetFlags(WindowManagerFlags.Fullscreen, WindowManagerFlags.Fullscreen);
Window.DecorView.SystemUiVisibility = (StatusBarVisibility)(
SystemUiFlags.LayoutStable |
SystemUiFlags.LayoutHideNavigation |
SystemUiFlags.LayoutFullscreen |
SystemUiFlags.HideNavigation |
SystemUiFlags.ImmersiveSticky |
SystemUiFlags.Fullscreen);
```

This is my `style.xml`:

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="MyTheme.Base">
</style>
<style name="MyTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splashscreen</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm struggling for days...
put this in OnCreate method (mainactivity.cs)

```
public class MainActivity : FormsAppCompatActivity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
        ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;
        this.Window.AddFlags(WindowManagerFlags.Fullscreen | WindowManagerFlags.TurnScreenOn);
        if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.Lollipop)
        {
            var stBarHeight = typeof(FormsAppCompatActivity).GetField("statusBarHeight", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic) ?? typeof(FormsAppCompatActivity).GetField("_statusBarHeight", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
            stBarHeight?.SetValue(this, 0);
        }

        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        Forms.Init(this, bundle);
        LoadApplication(new App());
    }



    public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, Permission[] grantResults)
    {
        PermissionsImplementation.Current.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }
}
```